# Can one mimic a cross-domain mod-rewrite rule?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cross-domain

Is it possible to mimic a rewrite rule, that will make `//domain1.com/anypagename.php?key=value` redirect to `//domain1.com/anypagename.php?key=value`, given that domain1.com and domain2.com reside on different host machines? Regular mod-rewrite doesn't allow this, but perhaps a combination of rewrite rules making everything point to the same file and have that file forward it, can mimic this?

The reason why I want to do this is because domain1 is a well-trusted subdomain of a large domain, so we want to keep this for marketing purposes, but we cannot change the DNS records and the associated hosting service is so terrible that we want the actual website to run on our own servers (and domain2.com is a regular domain under our control).

Methods using .htaccess, PHP etc. are all good, but it is important that both GET and POST request to arbitrary pages (with arbitrary ?key=val&key2=val2 arguments) on domain1 are correctly processed on domain2 and displayed as if they were actually regular pages on domain1.

Comment: Host records at the ISP or at the host server. If at the ISP I would query why you dont have access to modify it, if at the host server, move the website to a better host. If that too is not possible, I would query that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but the [`P|proxy`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) flag comes to mind

> For example, if you wanted all image requests to be handled by a back-end image server, you might do something like the following:
> ...

In your case, when `domain1.com` and `domain2.com` are set up identically, this could be

```
RewriteRule ^ http://domain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

However, note also

> **Performance warning**
>
> Using this flag triggers the use of mod_proxy, without handling of persistent connections. This means the performance of your proxy will be better if you set it up with ProxyPass or ProxyPassMatch

---

So [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) might be the better alternative

```
ProxyPass / http://domain2.com
```

But there's a drawback to this one too, you cannot use it in an .htaccess file. This works only, if you have access to the main or virtual host configuration.

Comment: I'm struggling to get this working. My .htaccess file has lines `RewriteEngine On` and `RewriteRule ^ http://domain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [P]` but now I get `Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at domain1.com Port 80'. However, directly visiting domain1.com/index.html works.

Comment: (I should note that the .htaccess is triggered, since removing it displays domain1's index.html file instead of this error.)

Comment: Late correction: the last sentence of my first comment should have been: However, directly visiting "domain2.com/index.html" works.

Comment: And when I add `ProxyPass "/test/" "http://domain2.com/test/"` I get an internal server error when surfing to `domain1.com/test`. :-(

Comment: As I wrote at the end, `ProxyPass` cannot be used in an .htaccess file. You must put it in the main or virtual host configuration.

Comment: Derp. Ok, no clue what I did wrong with the first approach, but the second approach seems to work now. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried the first approach in my test environment, and it does work. Maybe the error.log gives some hint on why this fails.

Comment: `[Sat Mar 25 16:46:07.034251 2017] [core:error] [pid 6514] (2)No such file or directory: [client 157.193.5.39:58755] AH00132: file permissions deny server access: proxy:http://domain2.com/test/index.html` (where domain2 was of course my actual domain). I'm not sure what to think of this, since domain2 is on another physical server and hence the file permissions are not even directly visible.

Comment: Strange, according to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/34093167/1741542, this hints at a missing mod_proxy. Never mind, ProxyPass is the preferred solution anyway.